# Вирусы на Linux

Tags: linux

На ноуте стоит единственная ось - Ubuntu. Иногда мне дают знакомые флешки, записать то да сё. А потом говорят, что на флешке много вирусов после меня. Заинтересовал вопрос. Вирусы, написанные в расчете на Windows, никакого влияния на линукса не оказывают. А могут ли они как-нибудь размножаться/передаваться на другие носители через линукс? То есть, действительно ли мог на флешку знакомого попасть вирус, если явно я его туда не отправлял.

Comment: Если был скачан или записан зараженный файл, то хотя вирус не будет никак работать на лине, при переносе на винду он активизируется. 

Кстати,есть версии популярных антивирусников для линя(DrWeb, NOD32 и др.) + бесплатные свободнораспростаняемые. Можете что-то такое установить и проверить Ваш компьютер, а вдруг где-то что-то сидит и дремлет.

Comment: @mikillskegg - да ну, причина того что под линем практически никогда не бывает вирусов даже не в том, что без вашего разрешения ничего не выполниться, а то, что писать вирусы под него не выгодно =). Сравните 90%+ пользователей форточек и около 1% линем

Comment: Да тут вообще о другом речь. Кстати, вирус, написанный под линь, наврят ли будет работать в винде)))

Comment: Я к этому и клоню - это не рентабельно ^.^

Comment: Банальный холивар на тему вирус под линем предлагаю закрыть. К тому же это 100% оффтоп. Одно последнее замечание. Господа виндопоклонники, ну напишите хотя бы для академического интереса хоть один серьезный вирус под линукс. Мне было  бы безумно интересно на него посмотреть. Наверняка это должен быть шедевр программистской мысли.

Comment: Мне тоже интересно =)

Comment: Господам виндопоклонникам это не нужно ;)

Вообще это один из видов butthurt'a, почему-то думать, что форточники поголовно боятся линуха, не пишут под него вири именно потому, что не могут, а еще не сидят под ним и не изучают, потому что он страшный и непонятный простым юзерам. А разгадка-то проста: нам это не интересно. Хватит уже требовать внимания, а то как веганы, ей-богу) Они тоже считают, что все нормальные люди слишком тупые и безвольные, чтобы встать на единственный истинный путь.

Comment: Да вообще речь о другом. Мне просто надоели эти разговоры, что, мол, вирусов под никсы нет, потому что это никому не нужно, а так это такие же дырявые системы, даже хуже. Ну пусть докажут обратное, хоть один реальный пример. Вот тогда и будем разговаривать. И нет тут никакой религии (во всяком случае, у меня). Исключительно академическая беседа.

Comment: Почти уверен что все на самом деле весьма банально - люди видят системные файлы типа .trash (это корзина в лине и маке кто не знает) и воспринимают их как вирусы т.к. не знают что это. Сам видел такую реакцию у человека, а потом выяснилось что он просто впервые флешку в свой мак накануне вставил.

Comment: В вирусе под линь больше работы психологической - подсунуть бинарник пропатченный или заджойнить его в багнутый софт, которого там пруд пруди (другого мало). Причем именно в софт, который sudo для нормального запуска требует. Учитывая, в каком виде обычно поставляется линуксовый софт, это не проблема. Суть не в сложности, суть в муторности задачи. Ну и я просто никогда вирями не занимался, не люблю ломать. Мож кто из деструктивных объявится, но вряд ли он кроме как "на слабо" ответит что-то другое.

Comment: В 2005 меня привлекали, чтобы выяснить источник распространения вируса. Пораженная система рассылала большие объемы подозрительного трафика. Внимание отдела специальных технических мероприятий случай привлек потому, что на этой машинке крутился сервер региональных властей. Выяснили, что заражение произошло через уязвимость в устаревшей версии PHPBB (форум), позволявшей выполнить любой код. Начальный скрипт скачивал основной код, присоединяющий машину к ботнету LinuxDay. Итог: 1) вирусы под Linux есть, 2) это на 100% социальная инженерия, так как ПО не обновлялось, апач был запущен от рута.

Comment: Лет пять назад мы руткит на RedHat поймали. Откуда взялся так и не разобрались. Переставили, IP и пароли сменили. 

Больше лично не видел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вирусы на XP, на exe в основном и на скриптах, на Linux-e такого быть не может, потому что программы без вашего разрешения не запускаются, а на XP может быть.

Comment: Сами давно уже нигде не запускаются, абсолютное большинство заражений — ручки непонимающих или обманутых пользователей. А под GNU/Linux не обмануть (подменив исполнимому бинарнику значок на «папку», ага) только потому, что система метаданных до сих пор представляет собой один большой уродливый костыль а-ля `gvfs-metadata`, который нельзя переносить.

Answer (score 4):

Мог конечно. Никто не мешает для udev  написать правила, которые будут на флешку копировать всякую гадость, когда ее вставили.
Вирусы, написанные для виндовс "веселым школьником" вполне могут запуститься под wine. Проверьте его наличие у себя.

Но есть один способ, как мог попасть вирус наверняка. Вы у кого то скопировали флешку, а потом скопировали это другу. Файлы вируса для линукса будут безобидными, но под виндой снова оживут.

С другой стороны, для большинства не важно, что у вас Убунта. Важно то, что нет антивируса:) Поэтому вирус у Вас, а не у всех тех других "друзей с виндой и антивирусом".

Answer (score 1):

*Из комментария пользователя [@aknew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2088/aknew):*

Почти уверен, что всё на самом деле весьма банально — люди видят системные файлы типа `.trash` (кто не знает — это корзина в лине и маке) и воспринимают их как вирусы, так как не знают, что это. Сам видел такую реакцию у человека, а потом выяснилось, что он просто впервые флешку в свой мак накануне вставил.